# Ionic Keyboard is not open properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am creating a login screen in Ionic. The problem is that when I click on the input field to open the Keyboard, it's not opening.

Then I click outside on the input field and then click on the input field then the keyboard is visible OR I click on the input fields 3 to 4 times and after that the Keyboard is visible.

I want to open the keyboard when I click on the input field for the first time. I've implemented the focusing code but it is not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the code

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example" version="1.0.21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App Name </name>
    <description>App Name</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="4.2" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />

    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>To scan barcodes</string>
        </edit-config>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker" spec="5.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-certificates" spec="^0.6.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-http" spec="1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^2.0.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="e363211c" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Production" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="0.9.3" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.2.26:8100" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
</widget>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "App Name ",
  "version": "1.0.21",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "./cordovaOverride.sh",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source_map"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-preferences": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@zxing/library": "0.5.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "1.26.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "2.156.0",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-pdf-generator": "^2.0.8",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner-browser-support": "7.1.22",
    "cordova-plugin-certificates": "^0.6.4",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-http": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
    "@types/node": "8.5.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "webpack": "3.8.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-certificates": {},
      "cordova-plugin-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-pdf-generator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "e363211c",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com",
        "MAX_STORE": "2"
      },
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-printer": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<!-- Page content inputs -->
<ion-content padding class="background">

    <ion-list>
        <!-- logo on top of page -->
        <ion-item no-lines justify-content-center align-items-center>
            <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
                <ion-col>
                    <div style="text-align: center">

                        <img align='center' src="assets/icon/logo.png" height="140px" width="180px">
                    </div>
                </ion-col>

            </ion-row>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item no-lines
                  style="height:40px; user-select: auto; padding-right:16px;border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;border-radius:3px;border-color: #E3e3e3">
            <ion-label color="dark" item-left>
                <ion-icon name="md-mail"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input style="user-select: auto" class="text_style" type="email" placeholder="Email"
                       [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Password Field with show/hide option controls-->
        <ion-item no-lines
                  style=" user-select: auto; padding-right:16px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;border-radius:3px;border-color: #E3e3e3">


            <ion-label color="dark" item-left>
                <ion-icon name="md-lock"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>


            <ion-input style="user-select: auto" class="ion-input" [(ngModel)]="password" type="{{type}}"
                       placeholder="Password" name="password"></ion-input>


            <button class="ion-input-button" *ngIf="!showPass" ion-button clear color="dark" type="button" item-right
                    (click)="showPassword()">
                <ion-icon name="md-eye-off"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button class="ion-input-button" *ngIf="showPass" ion-button clear color="dark" type="button" item-right
                    (click)="showPassword()">
                <ion-icon name="md-eye"></ion-icon>
            </button>


        </ion-item>
        <!--Forgot Password Link -->
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <!-- <ion-item> -->
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rememberLogin" (ionChange)="keepMeLogin()"
                                  style="margin-top:13px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:16px"></ion-checkbox>
                    <ion-label style="text-align:left; font-size: 12px; padding-top:4px">Remember Me</ion-label>

                </ion-row>

            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button clear color="button-color" style="text-align:right; font-size: 12px"
                        (click)="forgotPassword()" float-right>Forgot Password
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <!--Login Button -->
        <button style="height:48px" ion-button full color="button-color" (click)="onLogin()">Log in</button>

    </ion-list>
    <!-- </ion-card-content>
</ion-card> -->
    <!-- Create New Account Link -->

</ion-content>
<!--End content -->
```

Comment: Works fine in my device. My device is Redmi K20 Pro. Deploy the same code in other device and check it once.

Comment: Do you also use same config and package file with its same versions which I am mention in my question.

Comment: Not with exactly same configuration. Tried in Ionic 4.

Comment: Yes that is my point it is not working with same configuration. And want to know the reason.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: the same problem, did you solved?